# Locating controllers using Dependency Injection in MVC with Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am working on an MVC 5 application that utilizes Castle Windsor. I've separated my code using areas to make it more manageable. I have also updated my instantiated class of IWindorInstaller to include an extra method that will find the controllers from this new area.

My code looks like this:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(FindStandardControllers());
    container.Register(FindAdminControllers());
}

private BasedOnDescriptor FindStandardControllers()
{   
    return Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn<IController>()
        .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<HomeController>())
        .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
        .LifestyleTransient();
}

private BasedOnDescriptor FindAdminControllers()
{
    return Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn<IController>()
        .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<AdminController>())
        .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
        .LifestyleTransient();
}
```

All of this works, but is there a better way to tell Windsor to automagically pick up all the controllers from each new area?

I'm especially concerned if I want to include similarly named controllers (eg: HomeController) in each area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your controllers are inherited from `IController` you shouldn't specify namespace and suffix.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(
        Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .LifestyleTransient()
    );
}
```

In case you have controllers with the same name they will be in different namespaces and Windsor will resolve them correctly.

Comment: Thank you. That seems much easier than what I was trying to do.